# sails.js - Error : ENOENT appears during sails lift

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Sometimes , when i lift the sails server , i am getting the below mentioned error:

```
Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\user\project\.tmp\public\linker\js\sails.io.
js'
Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\user\project\.tmp\public\linker\js\app.js'
```

Operating System used : Windows 7

Why this error is coming often ?

### EDITED

I realised that problem is due to .tmp . Everytime when we refresh , .tmp is cleaned and the files are added again.

So , when i run my project , sometimes the web page is broken(ie no image or css files are loaded , only plain text) and error is thrown from .tmp that files are missing due to the delay in addition of files in .tmp.

Please help.Please advise me to solve the issue.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's coming from Grunt.  Try removing the `.tmp` folder completely, make sure you have permissions to create new files in `project`, and re-lifting.

Comment: Ya i have the permission. to create new files and relifting. i removed .tmp folder. thanks for ur quick reply. How this .tmp folder is created ? Will it be created everytine when i do sails lift? sorry iam new to sails.js if iam wrong pls correct me.Thanks

Comment: The .tmp folder is created by Grunt, and it holds all of your sites public assets so that Sails can serve them.  It will be created any time you do `sails lift` if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: So to avoid the above mentioned error , how can i proceed?

Comment: After you remove `.tmp` and relift, do you still get the error?

Comment: ya sometimes...when i lift sails..i get that error.

Comment: Error: EPERM, stat 'C:\xyz\abc\abcd\.tmp\public\video\abc.mp4'..iam getting this error also often .